# stat.h unavailable in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file

When I do `#include <stat.h>` in Linux, I get a compiler error. I need this library for the `S_IWRITE` flag, which in its turn is used in the context of system-level IO.

Is stat.h unavailable in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stat.h is available under the "sys" folder, try to #include it from there or add it to the list of include directories.

Comment: for clarification, include if from there means `#include <sys/stat.h>`, don't add it to your list of includes unless you really really have to though.

Answer (score 0):

From `man stat.h`:

```
NAME
       sys/stat.h - data returned by the stat() function

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/stat.h>
```